# How can I add exceptions to a .htaccess redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I need to exclude some directories from oldsite so they don't get redirected. What do I have to do? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(directory name)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can have multiple `RewriteCond` or you can use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(test|test2|test3)
```

Where test can be replace with your directory name which you want to exclude from redirection.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: Never mind, it was a browser problem, it does work. Thanks a lot